# What is the relation between KE of a nucleus and thermal radiation?

Tags: thermal-radiation

In a monoatomic gas the KE of an atom is 3/2 kT, so at room temp (300K) its speed is roughly 15 Km/s, is that right?

Can you tell how to figure out the parameters of a nucleus in a lattice
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPxhIRLW7G8

whose temp is 300K? I would imagine that the overall KE is the same of a monoatomic gas, but how do I find the speed and displacement of the nucleus? 300K corresponds to 6.2*10^12 Hz, is therefore its energy roughly 10^13Hz? what is max speed and displacement of the atom? I suppose the latter must be less than the atom size, so: 10^-11/12 cm, so I speculated that if the average speed is 15 Km/s then in one second there should be 10^18 oscillations, but would such oscillation produce a thermal radiation of much higher intensity?

Can you explain what does really happen? if you can't, could you please confirm whether a temp of 300K implies  that the nucleus oscillates 6.2*10^12 times per second?